# Initialize database in code-first SQLite

Tags: c#, wpf, code-first

Config that I set `connectionstring` to:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="default" connectionString="data source=database\data.db;" providerName="System.Data.SQLite" />
</connectionStrings>
```

But in `myDbContext` I change my database location to :

```
base.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = @"data source=" + AppVariable.myPath + @"database\data.db;";
```

After that when my app launch my tables are not created, where is the problem?

Comment: You don't seem to have providername.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

extract from my code with nuget package...no need of connection string and datasource...

```
using SQLite;

public string SQLitePath => Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "xxxxx.sqlite");


try
        {
            using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(SQLitePath) { Trace = IsDebug })
            {
                List<TargetModel> test = db.Table<TargetModel>().Select(p => p).ToList();
                return test;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            BusinessLogger.Manage(ex);
            return null;
        }
```